# IntelliJ - Could not save project: null

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a Play/Scala project that I've imported into IntelliJ 13. Every now and then, the IDE will pop up with an error dialog that says `Could not save project: null`.

Sometimes restarting IntelliJ will fix the issue, but I'd really like to know the cause of it and how to stop it permanently. I'd include more details, but I'm not really sure what's relevant yet.

Comment: I would suggest to report this as a bug on youtrack.jetbrains.com ...

Comment: Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be that an exception happened during saving. Check the log (Help | Show log) to see if that is the case. Then report a bug with the log attached.